# Null Pointer error in OnCreate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate

So I'm getting a Null Pointer error on line 33 of my project but I can't tell what it is. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activiy
ComponentInfo{yc.android.yourchallenger/yc.android.yourchallenger.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at yc.android.yourchallenger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-15 21:15:24.813: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the MainActivity where I am getting the error
        package yc.android.yourchallenger;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String [] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;    
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.nav_drawer, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);           
        }           
    }

 private void selectItem(int position) {
     Fragment fragment = new CreateFragment();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("key", position);
     fragment.setArguments(args);

     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                       .commit();
     // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
 }   

 @Override
 public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
     mTitle = title;
     getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
 }


}
```

Comment: it looks like mDrawerList is null in the line         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new DrawerItemClickListener());

Comment: @Zusee Weeking Line 33 is `mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,`

Comment: Make sure that you have ListView called left_drawer inside your activity_main layout. Check spellings carefully.

Comment: I try to create my drawer view in an xml file called drawer, so I have `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`... in there, and I do have the left_drawer, but should i switch that to my activity_main.xml?

Comment: Try the answer I suggested below and see..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your activity's layout contains a ListView with the `android:id="@+id/left_drawer"`, otherwise the call to `findViewById()` will return null.

Comment: I do have a file called nav_drawer.xml that contains that has `android:id="@+id/left_drawer`

Comment: But your Activity's layout is `activity_main.xml` according to the code you posted. You have to have the LIstView with this id **in the layout your activity is using**

Comment: Awesome. It works now. I don't have the reputation to +1, but I will when I do.

Answer (score 0):

As I  suggested in the comment, make sure that you have `ListView` called **left_drawer** inside your `activity_main layout`. Otherwise you can't call it using `findViewById()`.

You did not add any values to your  `mNavigationDrawerItemTitles` string array and it is added to the adapter. Also called `setOnItemClickListener()`. But there are not values in the list. Because your `mNavigationDrawerItemTitles` is empty. Add some values to the string array and test.